# struts jquery anchor tag not showing

Tags: struts2-jquery

Struts jquery anchor tag is not showing in the form

```
<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />

<!--  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<s:form id="form">
........................
..........................


<s:url var="ajaxReport" value="/report.action"/>
<sj:a id="sumbit" formIds="form" buttonText="Sumbit" indicator="indicator"  
       button="true" buttonIcon="ui-icon-refresh" > Submit</sj:a>

</s:form>
```

In this only the submit text is displayed. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Anything in your JS console? I'm wary of including your own jQuery as well as that of the plugin.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes you are right i removed it and it work perfectly, thanks

Comment: @DaveNewton post the comment as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<sj:head />` tag already includes the jQuery libraries. Including them again usually causes problems, and the JS console may provide a clue.